# Kotlin/Native -> androidMain -> Unresolved symbol

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have added this line in common gradle.

```
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0")
```

I'm tring to instantiate `FusedLocationProviderClient` inside a class in `androidMain`.

But it says, `unresolved symbol`. Any idea why?

Comment: Welcome! Could you add some more context please?

Comment: Can you post your gradle file

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish here is not possible the exact same way you are architecting this.

In the common, you cannot have platform specific implementations. In the common, you can add the code that is platform agnostic. The `FusedLocationProviderClient` is android specific. So, that dependencies you have with

```
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0")
```

must be placed for the android's dependencies block. And if you need android specific dependencies, you will need android SDK, and `android {}` block in your gradle file as well. Something like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(21)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
    }
}
```

And then in `kotlin{}` block, you can have this:

```
kotlin {
...
    sourceSets {
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                ...
                implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0")
                ...

            }
        }
...
}
```

Also, note that you might need `AndroidManifest.xml` in `src/main` to define the packge. Something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.packageName" />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Exactly that's what I did. I have a class inside "androidMain" and where I want to access FusedLocationProviderClient, but it says "unresolved symbol". I can't even get the Activity class. It seems like I can't access any android specific libraries.

Comment: Sometimes things get a bit muddled up. Have you tried `Clear Cache/Restart`?